# When to use “using backup controlfile” in Oracle

Tags: oracle, backup, database-backups, oracle11gr2

I know this is something not new to ask, however, I did not get the satisfactory answer where and where not to use "RECOVER DATABASE USING BACKUP CONTROLFILE" or "RECOVER DATABASE UNTIL CANCEL USING BACKUP CONTROLFILE".

It will really help if someone can explain with proper examples and scenarios.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is quite verbose: If the original/current controlfiles are not available you can resort to using a backup controlfile.

The controlfile contains the layout und state of the database:

- files comprising the database.
- current SCN, the system change number, incremented with each transaction.

The datafiles also store the respective SCN. If the SCN in the controlfile is lower than the SCN in the datafile Oracle knows it is dealing with a backup controlfile.

One scenario where this is used is creating a copy of a productive database for testing. To this purpose you can do the following:

- Restore the controlfile from the backup on the test server. Now the file layout of the database is known (and can be adapted if necessary).
- Restore the data files.
- Start recovering the database (USING BACKUP CONTROLFILE).
- Recovery will consume archived redo logs you will have to provide. Stop by canceling the recovery after a redo log (e.g. the last available one) or by specifying a point in time (PIT recovery).
- Open the database with RESETLOGS option.

Usually the the database is also renamed to avoid confusion.

Another scenario is a recovery due to a datafile restored from a backup. In that case the current controlfile is available and USING BACKUP CONTROLFILE is not needed.

Comment: So if i have 1 week old Control file along with all Archive log files, i have chances to recover the database completely or partially as per the requirement and in both the cases i have to use "using backup controlfile". And if any of the archive file is missing, we cant use this feature because there is no chance we can match the SCN with the datafiles, only option left is to create a controlfile and do the recovery. Let me know if understanding correct or need any correction.

Comment: If you have 1 week old control file + data files + archive logs: then yes, you can recover the database with using backup control file. If archive logs are missing you can only recover up to the gap.

Comment: Given that an online backup and subsequent archive logs exist it should also be possible to create a new set of controlfiles via `CREATE CONTROLFILE`. The result of course also not the original controlfile and `USING BACKUP CONTROLFILE` is necessary. It's a while I've done that though.

Comment: Okay, can you put some light on when we create a controlfile, from where it picks up the SCN to store in the controlfile and accordingly when we give "using backup controlfile", how does it know from where to start recovery? I will definitely test this out but its good to know from where it picks the SCN?

Comment: As I said in my answer: The datafiles also store the respective SCN. You can find some examples here: [recovery details](http://avdeo.com/2008/05/29/oracle-database-recovery-details/). There it is also pointed out that with a backup controlfile the recovery must be terminated by the admin: There is no way for the database to know that no further recovery is possible as only the original controlfile notes the current SCN for the whole database.

Answer (score -3):

1) When all controlfles are lost
2) When database backup is older than controlfile backup.